# How to fully control Raspberry Pi over Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi

I have a Raspberry Pi and a Wi-Fi dongle. I want to be able to fully control my Raspberry Pi over Wi-Fi from my notebook running Windows 8.

Is it possible to accomplish this? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Fully control how? Command line? Gui?

Comment: @CanadianLuke - Fully control is achievable over CLI - it simply means logging in as root or equivalent - what would make a GUI have any more control than the CLI?

Comment: It's just very open ended, in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

"Over wifi" is somewhat vague - which device will be acting as the access point, the Pi, the notebook , or a router?

Once you have both the Pi and the notebook connected to the same wifi (and provided wireless isolation is disabled), you should be able to ssh into the pi and have access to it - ssh as root or equivalent, and you will have full access.

In order to SSH into the Pi, you will need either it's IP address or it's network name - the network name can be configured in the Pi, but the IP address depends on how you intend to configure the wifi network.

You will also need a [SSH server enabled and running on the Pi](http://cplus.about.com/od/raspberrypi/a/How-Do-I-Setup-Ssh-On-Raspberry-Pi.htm)

While there are many programs that can be used to SSH into the Pi, [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is probably the most common one used by windows

Answer (score 1):

You can fully control it via

CMD:  `ssh -X username@ipadress`

GUI: if you want to get a sort of remote desktop, you can use VNC: http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server